# Java : 2D Sidescroller Terrain

Tags: java, 2d, perlin-noise

Okay so After all this Edits here is the main question. How I can generate Terrain with a 2d Simplex Noise Algorithm, I am deletng old info so the post its more readble. I´ve been doing some tests and here are my results so far. Any help is appreciated. Any Ideas why my code isnt working?

I am far from getting a good result, Here is an Image, I am using The Simplex Noise genrator Timothy oferred to me (thanks :D)

[image: Simplex Noise Test 1]

And Heres is the Code:

```
public void GenerateChunk(float offsetX, int amplitude, long seed)
{


    // Its += 16 Because each block is 16 pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE; x += 16)
    {
            PerlinNoise.genGrad(seed);
            float height = (float) PerlinNoise.noise(x, 0);
            System.out.print(height);

            for(int y = 0; y < height * 16; y += 16){

                try {

                    Block B = new Block(Material.DIRT, x, y + 400, new Image("res/Dirt.png"));
                    Blocks.add(B);
                    B.setVisible(true);

                } catch (SlickException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }


     }
}
```

Here its where I call it

```
world.getChunk(0, 0).GenerateChunk(4, 12, 1231233876); // 12312 etc is a test number for the seed.
```

Finally here is the example output (height value)

```
0.0-0.3244323-0.4746854-0.6980603-0.212961030.437604370.0-0.013018643-0.3333134-0.49871972-0.498743-0.226263150.43900093-0.305881470.026026215-0.341923240.0-0.3244323-0.4746854-0.6980603-0.212961030.437604370.0-0.013018643-0.3333134-0.49871972-0.498743-0.226263150.43900093-0.305881470.026026215-0.34192324
```

Comment: How are you calling the code that's supposed to generate the noise?

Comment: I just added my code

Comment: Ok, i gave you an answer, but *do* please look up how perlin noise works.
If you'd understood perlin noise, you could probably have figured this out yourself. ;)

Comment: You're now making "massive" 16 unit jumps in the height you're passing to the noise function : `for(int y = 0; y < height * 16; y += 16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things come to mind :

First off, you're generating noise, but you're using the wrong functions of the noise generator in order to have things like a seed.

The second thing, is that because of the way you generate your chunks, you're not keeping track of the offset of the chunk you're generating, resulting in the same bit of terrain being repeated continuously.

Lastly, you can "scale" perlin noise, making the output seem smoother. this especially works if you're generating "blocks" like you're doing.

You should be using something like this:

```
float persistence = 0;
float octaves = 1; //<-- higher octaving means more detailed terrain
float terrainScale = 10; // <-- higher scale means bigger, seemingly smoother terrain

//offsetX is the highest X value of the LAST chunk + 1
public void GenerateChunk(float offsetX, int amplitude)
{

    GenerateEmptyChunk();

    // Its += 16 Because each block is 16 pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE; x += 16)
    {
            float height = (float) PerlinNoise.PerlinNoise1D((offsetX+x)/terrainScale, persistence, octaves);

                //this is also far from optimal, but i'm sure you can come up with something better.
                for(Block B : Blocks)
                {
                    if(B.getX() == x)
                    {
                    //  System.out.print(B.getX() + "Block");
                        B.setY((int) (400 + (height * amplitude)));
                        B.setVisible(true);

                    }
                }
     }
}
```

::update::

Looking at the code you edited into the question this should just about get you there. (can't test it obviously so use with caution)

```
//make sure you call this before you start generating cunks!
//you will only need it once.
public void SetSeed(long seed)
{
    PerlinNoise.genGrad(seed);
}


//and since doing all the work related to setting the seed needs to be done only once, we can remove them from the function
public void GenerateChunk(float offsetX, float amplitude)
{
    for(float x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x += 1)
    {
            for(int subX = 0; subX < 16; subX += 1)
            {
                try 
                {
                    //since we want "1d" noise, we always pass 0 as the y coordinate.
                    //we also don't pass the "multiplied by 16" x coordinate into the noise generator because that would distort the outcome.
                    float height = (float) PerlinNoise.noise(x+offsetX, 0);
                    height *= amplitude;

                    //400 seems to be offset height, you might still want to move that to the function call as a parameter.
                    //notice that i'm multiplying the x offset by 16 here rather than before possing it to the noise generator.
                    Block B = new Block(Material.DIRT, offsetX+(x*16), height + 400, new Image("res/Dirt.png"));
                    Blocks.add(B);
                    B.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (SlickException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
     }
 }
```

Comment: First of All Thanks for replying almost anyone is replying. Well, I did wha you said and know I have better Results.But Still some problems. I edited the main post with images so you can see it

Comment: Any ideas about the tile generator?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I made a reading SNAFU. what i thought was the seed really isn't the seed, it's the persistence.
Changing the persistence changes how rough your terrain is.
This noise implementation doesn't support seeds by the look of it

Comment: Your best bet is just to find a different noise generator that supports seeds.
One that does perlin or even simplex noise.
Then you still need to "snap" the position of your tiles to the grid after generating the tiles themselves.

Comment: You can find a decent simplex noise implementation that supports seeds Here : http://pastebin.com/354PnhnX

Comment: Thanks, I already saw this Simplex Noise code but I didnt find a way to implement, 2D Noise isnt used for 3D enviroment? and !D for 2D? Anyway how what I am supposed to put in y a random value or an  offset? I asked a question about this but with no answer  :(. Hope you can help me :D.

Anyway Thanks very much :D

Comment: it doesn't matter that it can generate noise in two directions if you're only using one. just use the X input, and keep the Y input the same

Comment: (don't randomise the Y input if you do this.)

Comment: So now I am using the Simplex noise and I ´m leaving the Y value at 0.But I am very far from getting a good result. I am uploading an image to the main post

Comment: Updated the answer to match the new code.
When you call this function, amplitude determines how steep the hills and valleys of your terrain will be (so don't pass `0` or you'll end up with flat terrain)

Comment: This is what i needed, Now I will have to make some changes, like aligning blocks and making the chunk system, also add more blocks.

Thank you very much this was the base code  i needed

Comment: All right, good luck and have fun :)